# How do i split a line and store the contents in 3 different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee

I have the following input

```
21 22 24

31 32 34
```

How can i split the lines in java, and put "21, 31" in an array, "22,32" in another array and "24,34" in another array.

I wrote the following code as of now

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test{
  public static void main(String []args){
    String[] line;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
      {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
          line = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
          String first = line[0];
          String second = line[1];
          String second = line[1];
        }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

I have trouble with putting the first column values, second column values and third column values in their corresponding arrays.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: try reading the Java tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown:  The API can only suggest how to read from one line, but not two at the same time.  In most actuality though, this seems pretty straightforward - are you at least familiar with how to read in this input, and split it up?

Comment: What part of this assignment you have trouble with? Reading lines? Getting numbers from lines? Creating arrays? Can we see at leas pseudocode of how you imagine this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 2):

Since multidimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays you can create array with sizes `[3][2]`. First dimension represents number of inner arrays, second their length. You want 3 arrays for 2 elements.

Now pseudocode to solve this task can look like this

```
create array[3][2];//this will hold 3 smaller arrays which can hold 2 elements 
for row = 1..2 //iterate over lines
   for wordNumber = 1..3 //iterate over words
      write to array[wordNumber] at position [row] current number
```

This way first array will contain first numbers from each lines, second array will have middle numbers, and third array will have last numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using collections to minimise the chance of needing to recode this every time you make a change to the size

Something like the following will give you a column arraylist with each value stored into a dynamic variable that you can do whatever you need to with

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> columns = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        columns.add(new ArrayList<String>());//Col 1
        columns.add(new ArrayList<String>());//Col 2
        columns.add(new ArrayList<String>());//Col 3

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
      {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
String sLine[] = sCurrentLine .split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < sLine.length; i++)
        {
            columns.get(i).add(sLine[i]);
        }
}
      } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```